# CSS will not appear with HTML and Node

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

CSS styling will not appear with my HTML when running in Node.

Directory:

Login_Page_V2.html
Login_Page_V1.js
public
    -css
                 -style.css

My server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/Login_Page_V2.html'));
});
```

HTML code:

```
    link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/css/styleProject.css"/
```

Comment: try to use `<link href="/public/css/styleProject.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your static middleware at `/public`.

```js
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Without adding that middleware path, express is looking for the uri of `/public/css/styleProject.css` inside the `public` directory (essentially, trying to reference the file at `${__dirname}/public/public/css/styleProject.css`). By specifying the path for your static middleware, you avoid this duplication and improve performance since only uris prefixed with `/public/` will be looked up on the file system.